# BSC-Testnet Contract verification Fails: Error! Unable to generate Contract ByteCode and ABI

Tags: solidity, contract-development, testnets, bsc, contract-verification

I've been struggling with this with different methods. As the most straightforward, I tried manually-flattening the code in REMIX, and verifying it on bscscan. Compiler version OK, Runs for optimization 200 OK, Optimization ON... and it always fail.

Then I tried with hardhat, and truffle, with truffle compile and verifying I got a very similar result. I think I have checked all possible options about this and I can't fix it.

I will be gratefull if any mate could give some advice.

Contract address: https://testnet.bscscan.com/token/0x64Af478C02a6Cd509EC17F11578336e8A6F3Cd5f

BSC Scan testnet output:

```
Compiler Version: v0.8.0+commit.c7dfd78e
Optimization Enabled: True
Runs: 200
ByteCode (what we are looking for):
608060...0000000000009f5094675526898e4260a411241d3742320211830000000000000000000000003c65000c36c1eb831d923c712291b25331694e5c000000000000000000000000d8223cb81bd0cc47ed28f4ec2c3cec8b0db52816

- vs what we got -

We tried looking for a match from the list of compiled contract bytecode outputs (as listed below), but was unable to find an exact match.

1) Address
60566037600b82828239805160001a607314602a57634e487b7160e01b600052600060045260246000fd5b30600052607381538281f3fe73000000000000000000000000000000000000000030146080604052600080fdfe{ipfs}64736f6c63430008000033ddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef00000000000000000000000058d299cf28e508704646a95d78aea4efddd6b7c8000000000000000000000000fe76f9f0af1f8250cb30767461921e81871d9037000000000000000000000000eaeeb732b67169f3bc24daa6271e95fc104e0fc0000000000000000000000000631bb0244071ac67663241657c8312ecdb23a665000000000000000000000000e8dd32180803095a57b4ff1b475753ea5d1c3b8d0000000000000000000000003c9e6083e2db441843c9d6678f1e54cc9bb5b719000000000000000000000000ddfacfd8b9da4c15f61beb43b41db12c33c6898f0000000000000000000000009f5094675526898e4260a411241d3742320211830000000000000000000000003c65000c36c1eb831d923c712291b25331694e5c000000000000000000000000d8223cb81bd0cc47ed28f4ec2c3cec8b0db52816

2) Ancestry
60806040....f{ipfs}64736f6c63430008000033ddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3efddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55...

3) SafeMath
60566037600b82828239805160001a607314602a57634e487b7160e01b600052600060045260246000fd5b30600052607381538...
```

Comment: How did you fix it? I am doing all correctly but I get the same error every time. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just compile & verify with HARDHAT as described [here](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/docs/guides/deploying)